# Login with phpmyadmin only works under Firefox, no error messages generated

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian-squeeze

I've setup a phpmyadmin site protected by an htaccess file. The site is also set up to force an SSL connection.

The problem is that everything works fine under Firefox but not other browsers (Opera, Chrome, Midori, ...)  Moreover, with the other browsers, I get no error message and using either a good or bad login will just refresh the login page.  There's nothing in the Apache/php logs, either.

I really don't understand why this only works with Firefox.

I'm using the last version of phpmyadmin 3.4.7.1 and up-to date-packages from Debian Squeeze.  Trying with the phpmyadmin version from Debian's repository also causes this error, and cleaning my browser's cookies, even uninstalling and reinstalling browsers doesn't help either.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the date and time on the server is accurate.

Comment: Why might this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been authenticating while testing your setup, I have noticed with phpmyadmin over SSL that it sometimes fails to authenticate, even when the credentials are right, when you have failed to authenticate properly before.

I suggest clearing caches and cookies and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any proxy settings or other network configs? Firefox generally doesn't use the same settings as Chrome.

Also, do pings to your server show up correctly? Also, in Chrome, use the Inspect element to check for network resources/loads.